# File Upload Location of Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, extensions, image-upload

I am developing a custom module for Magento 1. In this module there is a form field which uploads image. I would like to know the location of the uploaded image. Where can I find the uploaded images?

Comment: Can you please share file upload code, your detail is not sufficient for answer.

Comment: Thanks @JayeshPatel for your reply. I am new in Magento Module development. 

Here is my code(The name of the file is **form.php**).

`$fieldset->addField('image','file',
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('digitab_brandlogo')->__('Image'),
                'name'  => 'image',
            )
        ); `

Even I don't know Whether the file is uploaded properly or not. But I am getting success message.  Thanks for your reply

Comment: You sent code for `File` input, I was expecting code for handle uploaded file. No worries see my answer for more detail it might clear your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You need make custom code for uploading file in Magento. Magento has a class `Varien_File_Uploader` defined for this purpose.

See below code for more detail.

```
/* Handle file uploading */
if(count($_FILES['image']) > 0 and $_FILES['image']['name'] != '')
{
    try
    {
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image'); // Instantiate varien file uploader class with your $_FILE global variable
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('doc','pdf','txt','docx')); //Allowed extension for file
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true); //for creating the directory if not exists
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false); //if true, uploaded file's name will be changed, if file with the same name already exists directory.

        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'tmp_dir' . DS . 'files'; // Set your destination path for your file
        $fname = $_FILES['docname']['name']; //file name 

        if($uploader->save($path, $fname)){
            // You file has been uploaded to $path directory
        }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'Error Message: '.$e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Note: The destination directory should be writable

Hope this is helpful.